# Column is null using Case When SQL

Tags: sql, case, substitution, case-when

I'm using SQL Developer

I need to accept a user input as either Y or N.

If N is entered, I need to convert this to null. If Y is entered it should remain Y. The script then needs to search for a column with either a null value or a value of Y depending on what is entered by the user.

I have the code below with a decent idea for how to tackle it

accept WITHDRAWN char prompt 'Please enter Y or N)'

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE column1 = case when '&WITHDRAWN' = 'N' then null else '&WITHDRAWN' end;
```

As you can probably tell, it doesn't work, as for the column to be null, the '=' sign would need to be an 'is'. Likewise for the column to be 'Y' then the sign would need to be '='.

I really can't figure out a way to substitute N for the value of null and allow column1 to match up to this. Is it even possible?

Comment: substitute column1 instead of the user input.  `case when column1 is null then 'N' else 'Y' end =&withdrawn`  or simply use coalesce.  `coalesce(column1,'N') = &withdrawn`

Answer (score 1):

I'd coalesce the column1 value so when it's Null, N is substituted and compared to the user input.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE coalsece(column1,'N') = &WITHDRAWN;
```

Assumption being in table1 all column1's that are null are infact 'N' so the coalesce simply allows us to do a character to character comparison.

Also be aware that indexes on column1 will be ignored since we had to use a function to get the 'N' value returned.

Comment: anytime you use a function like this be warned the index if one exists likely can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT * FROM table1 
   WHERE (
       (column1 = '&&WITHDRAWN' AND '&&WITHDRAWN' = 'Y') 
    OR 
       (column1 IS NULL         AND '&&WITHDRAWN' = 'N'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need case at all:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE 
(
    '&WITHDRAWN' = 'N'
    AND Column1 IS NULL 
)
OR Column1 = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 
where (
    (column1 = '&WITHDRAWN' and '&WITHDRAWN' != 'N') 
  or 
    (column1 is null        and '&WITHDRAWN' = 'N'))
```

Hope this help!